# xwiki change bad title imported from confluence

Tags: confluence, xwiki

We have imported a space from confluence. Some of the page title in that import contains `/` which xwiki doesn't like. It throws 400 and its children also becomes inaccessible. Is there any way I can change the title from database or somewhere? I tried changing it from the table `xwikidoc` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Is there anything I need to do in order to change the page title from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by making changes in tomcat.service and allowing encoded slash and backslash. Here is what I added to an environment:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```

If someone needs, here is my tomcat.service looks like now:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

#Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS= -Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=400m -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```